# Trying to keep category values sorted in barplot

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe with about 3000 observations. I'm not just analyzing the whole, but also subsamples, which I create as follows:

**SNIIPPET 1:**

```
allophone.count.test <- subset (merged.data.for.study, Environment %in% curr.phon.env)
```

I have data in which the values for a certain category ("Allophone" in the data below) need to be presented in a specific order in barplots, which is as follows:

```
[p], [p̚], [pʰ], [p͡ɸ], [ɸ], [b], [b͡β], [β], OTHER, ∅
```

To establish the proper order, I've assigned numbers to the above values during part of the data processing process. The values then look like this:

```
01. [p], 02. [p̚], 03. [pʰ], 04. [p͡ɸ], 05. [ɸ], 06. [b], 07. [b͡β], 08. [β], 09. OTHER, 10. ∅
```

Here's a sample dataframe. Note that at this stage, Allophone and Allophone.Backup contain the same values, to make it easy to check for errors later):

```
allophone.count.test <- read.table(
    header=TRUE, sep="\t", text='Region Phoneme Allophone   Count   Total.Count Percentage  Allophone.Backup
LocationA   p   01. [p] 16  92  17.4    01. [p]
LocationA   p   02. [p̚]    4   92  4.3 02. [p̚]
LocationA   p   05. [ɸ] 8   92  8.7 05. [ɸ]
LocationA   p   06. [b] 5   92  5.4 06. [b]
LocationA   p   08. [β] 55  92  59.8    08. [β]
LocationA   p   09. OTHER   1   92  1.1 09. OTHER
LocationA   p   10. ∅   3   92  3.3 10. ∅
LocationB   p   01. [p] 19  136 14  01. [p]
LocationB   p   03. [pʰ]    1   136 0.7 03. [pʰ]
LocationB   p   05. [ɸ] 14  136 10.3    05. [ɸ]
LocationB   p   06. [b] 7   136 5.1 06. [b]
LocationB   p   08. [β] 88  136 64.7    08. [β]
LocationB   p   10. ∅   7   136 5.1 10. ∅'
)
```

This is all well and good, and all the plotting tools I've tried (barplot, ggplot2, and the [wrapper](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrxiaohe/R_Functions/master/functions/bar) that I'm currently using) duly order these values alphanumerically, so when I plot the data with the added numbers all is well. Unfortunately, these numbers make the plots look absurdly amateurish, and would not be accepted for publication. So I need to maintain the proper order while getting rid of the numbers.

The problem is that as soon as I try to plot the values with no numbers, all the plotting tools that I try revert to sorting them alphabetically.

Most proposed solutions to this problem that I've found say to convert it to a factor. The following is the code I'm using to (1) convert this into a factor and (2) get rid of the leading numbers + period + space:

**SNIPPET 2:**

```
allophone.count.test$Allophone <- factor (allophone.count.test$Allophone)
allophone.count.test$Allophone <- gsub ("[0-9][0-9]\\. ", "", allophone.count.test$Allophone, perl=TRUE)
```

This *looks* like it works, as seen below, as the Allophone values have no leading numbers, period or space, and the proper order is retained:

```
    Region  Phoneme Allophone   Count   Total.Count Percentage  Allophone.Backup
1   LocationA   p   [p] 16  92  17.4    01. [p]
2   LocationA   p   [p̚]    4   92  4.3 02. [p̚]
3   LocationA   p   [ɸ] 8   92  8.7 05. [ɸ]
4   LocationA   p   [b] 5   92  5.4 06. [b]
5   LocationA   p   [β] 55  92  59.8    08. [β]
6   LocationA   p   OTHER   1   92  1.1 09. OTHER
7   LocationA   p   ∅   3   92  3.3 10. ∅
8   LocationB   p   [p] 19  136 14.0    01. [p]
9   LocationB   p   [pʰ]    1   136 0.7 03. [pʰ]
10  LocationB   p   [ɸ] 14  136 10.3    05. [ɸ]
11  LocationB   p   [b] 7   136 5.1 06. [b]
12  LocationB   p   [β] 88  136 64.7    08. [β]
13  LocationB   p   ∅   7   136 5.1 10. ∅
```

But then I go to plot, and everything is made alphabetical again (I'm not using ggplot2 in my work, but rather the wrapper I linked to, but for illustration purposes here ggplot2 will do):

**SNIPPET 3:**

```
ggplot(allophone.count.test, aes(factor(Allophone), Count, fill = Region)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Now, I've found a partial solution which works *ONLY* when all possible values for Allophone are present (i.e. they have a Count > 1 in the particular subsample I'm processing at a given time). That is to assign the number-free versions of the Allophone values manually to the factor as labels:

**SNIPPET 4:**

```
allophone.count.test$Allophone <- factor (allophone.count.test$Allophone, labels = c("[p]", "[p̚]", "[pʰ]", "[p͡ɸ]", "[ɸ]", "[b]", "[b͡β]", "[β]", "OTHER", "∅"))
```

However, this is an extremely un-robust solution -- there are 10 possible values for Allophone, and they're not always all present in a given subsample (such as the one I've provided here). When that happens, R grinds to a halt.

**Is there a more robust way to do what I want to do with labels?** (Or any other way, for that matter?)

The best attempt I've been able to come up with (I'm neither a programmer nor a statistician) fails miserably -- it assigns the wrong labels to many values (compare Allophone and Allophone.Backup starting on the third line):

**SNIPPET 5:**

```
allophone.count.test$Allophone <- factor (
    allophone.count.test$Allophone, labels = unique (
        gsub ("[0-9][0-9]\\. ", "", allophone.count.test$Allophone, perl=TRUE)
    )
)

    Region  Phoneme Allophone   Count   Total.Count Percentage  Allophone.Backup
1   LocationA   p   [p] 16  92  17.4    01. [p]
2   LocationA   p   [p̚]    4   92  4.3 02. [p̚]
3   LocationA   p   [b] 8   92  8.7 05. [ɸ]
4   LocationA   p   [β] 5   92  5.4 06. [b]
5   LocationA   p   OTHER   55  92  59.8    08. [β]
6   LocationA   p   ∅   1   92  1.1 09. OTHER
7   LocationA   p   [pʰ]    3   92  3.3 10. ∅
8   LocationB   p   [p] 19  136 14.0    01. [p]
9   LocationB   p   [ɸ] 1   136 0.7 03. [pʰ]
10  LocationB   p   [b] 14  136 10.3    05. [ɸ]
11  LocationB   p   [β] 7   136 5.1 06. [b]
12  LocationB   p   OTHER   88  136 64.7    08. [β]
13  LocationB   p   [pʰ]    7   136 5.1 10. ∅
```

The following is almost the same. It seeks to assign the leading-numberless form to Allophone as a label. But it fails:

**SNIPPET 6:**

```
allophone.count.test$Allophone <- factor (
    allophone.count.test$Allophone, labels = gsub ("[0-9][0-9]\\. ", "", allophone.count.test$Allophone, perl=TRUE)
)

Error in factor(allophone.count.test$Allophone, labels = gsub("[0-9][0-9]\\. ",  : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 13 should be 1 or 8
```

And when I try to create levels to hold the bare Allophone values, I get a different error:

**SNIPPET 7:**

```
allophone.count.test$Allophone <- factor (
    allophone.count.test$Allophone, levels = gsub ("[0-9][0-9]\\. ", "", allophone.count.test$Allophone, perl=TRUE)
)

Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help anyone can give me. To reiterate, **the desired result is a barplot in which the order of the Allophone vector's numbered values is retained when the numbers are removed.**

*(EDIT: I've added "Snippet" headers for anyone who wants to refer to a specific bit of code, as this question is quite long).*

Comment: Your factor solution specifying all the levels is the way to go. When you have subsamples that don't contain all the levels of the Allophone factor, use `droplevels(dataframename)` to correct for this. As a side-note, while providing data etc can be useful, the level of detail you have in this question is way over the top.

Comment: I've edited my post with labels for various snippets of code. Could you let me know what snippet of my code you're referring to exactly? Actually, as I'm barely literate with R, it would be phenomenal if you could be more specific with your suggestion -- I haven't figured out how to assign levels to Allophone in the original dataframe (~3000 observations in long form), as I run into the same errors I detail above, and I can't assign them manually to subsets since I can't know what levels of Allophone will be in a given subset.

Comment: Snippet 4 is the way to go. Save yourself a variable called `allolevs` or something similar containing the order you want, and than just use `test$Allophone <- factor(test$Allophone, levels=allolevs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified example showing the logic of how this should work:

```
# specify the order of the variable you want:
levs <- c("[p]", "[β]", "OTHER", "∅")

# here's some example data I prepared earlier:
test <- data.frame(
  Region = rep(c("LocationA","LocationB"), c(4,4)),
  Allophone = levs[c(1,3,2,4,3,2,1,4)],
  Count = c(16, 4, 8, 5, 55, 1, 3, 19),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

#     Region Allophone Count
#1 LocationA       [p]    16
#2 LocationA     OTHER     4
#3 LocationA       [ß]     8
#4 LocationA         Ø     5
#5 LocationB     OTHER    55
#6 LocationB       [ß]     1
#7 LocationB       [p]     3
#8 LocationB         Ø    19

# convert the Allophone variable with the specified order:
test$Allophone <- factor(test$Allophone, levels=levs)

# do the plotting:    
ggplot(test, aes(Allophone, Count, fill = Region)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much -- I've gotten this to work thanks to your example. One doubt remains in my mind: does this obsolete the use of the `droplevels` function you mentioned above?

Comment: @GilWilliams - no, if say you took a subset of `test` as a new data.frame called `subtest`, and it only had the levels of `"[p]"` & `"[β]"`, then you would need to run `subtest <- droplevels(subtest)`. This would make sure that all the other categories not in the new subset would not be present on your barplot.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. My code seems to be robust and error-free now. Thanks a ton!